# Inheritance Query in Python

Tags: python

I've seen the following code:

```
class Spell(object):
    def __init__(self, incantation, name):
        self.name = name
        self.incantation = incantation

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + self.incantation + '\n' + self.get_description()

    def get_description(self):
        return 'No description'

    def execute(self):
        print self.incantation


    class Accio(Spell):
        def __init__(self):
            Spell.__init__(self, 'Accio', 'Summoning Charm')


    class Confundo(Spell):
        def __init__(self):
            Spell.__init__(self, 'Confundo', 'Confundus Charm')

    def get_description(self):
        return 'Causes the victim to become confused and befuddled.'


    def study_spell(spell):
        print spell
```

I don't understand why the following code Outputs `Summoning Charm Accio 
No description`. I'm confused why the `No description` is printed.

```
spell = Accio()
print spell
```

Thank You

Comment: It the code supposed to have "subclasses", or is the indentation weird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__str__` function is called when inbuild `str` or `print` statements are used with the objects. It is  used when an “informal” string representation of instances of that class is required.[(from the docs)](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

Two simplify little more,
The `print` statement cannot be used as such with the objects as the behaviour of the objects is not defined. `__str__` defines how the object must behave when used with `print` statement.

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + self.incantation + '\n' + self.get_description()
```

Here it prints the values of `self.name` and `self.incantation` which are `Summoning Charm Accio`
It also calls the `self.get_description()` which returns `No description` thus giving the output.

```
def get_description(self):
        return 'No description'
```

Answer (score 0):

`Spell.__str__()` calls `get_description()`, but `Accio` doesn't override `get_description()`.

Comment: While your answer is correct it may need more description to understand what's going on.